# vsc extension config throws "json transfered failure!" error

Tags: visual-studio-code

whenever i am editing any json file (no matter what extension i want to configure) inside the vscode folder i keep getting the error "xyz.json transfered failue!" as soon as i hit save.

i'd like to know what this error means and also how to fix it. the error itself does not give away any useful information...

[image: visual studio code transfered failure]

Answer (score 0):

ok stupid me...the extension "remoteSync" caused this error....